# Should Icompile luarocks 'as usual' or as a 'rock'?

Tags: lua

I installed Lua Rocks as instructed here:
https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Download#Installing

After './configure' I got a message to choose either:
'make build' then 'make install'
OR
'make bootstrap'

What's the difference between these two and which should I choose?

Comment: I don't know but I would assume that the bootstrap option requires luarocks to be already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the [ChangeLog](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Release-history):

> `make bootstrap` is now an advertised option for **installing LuaRocks itself as a rock** on Unix systems

That means that if you go this way you can upgrade `luarocks` via `luarocks install`:

> Those of you who installed LuaRocks 2.1.0 or later by using `make bootstrap` on Unix may upgrade by simply running: `luarocks install luarocks`

from [[ANN] LuaRocks 2.2.1](http://sourceforge.net/p/luarocks/mailman/message/33607776/).

Comment: Thank you. I credited you for an answer but still do not understand the difference between the result of bootstrap and install. Why does one choose on or the other? Is this like asking why are there so many computer languages??

Comment: Warning: falling   back to curl - install luasec to get native HTTPS support
    Installing https://rocks.moonscript.org/luarocks-2.2.1-2.src.rock...
    Using https://rocks.moonscript.org/luarocks-2.2.1-2.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode
    Updating manifest for /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
    luarocks 2.2.1-2 is now built and installed in /usr/local (license: MIT/X11)

    Checking stability of dependencies on the absence of
    luarocks 2.2.1-1...

    Removing luarocks 2.2.1-1...
    Removal successful.

Comment: then      'sudo luarocks install inspect'     then ran some test code and got a bunch of 'no file.......' errors. I think I have to fix my PATH.

Comment: But my point is that luarocks installed as bootstrap or as stnadard made no difference in running luarocks. Is it supposed to?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference AFAIK. `make bootstrap` is the mode advertised on the official [getting started](https://rocks.moonscript.org/#quick-start).